# Create timestamp based on a keyword

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, timestamp, keyword

I would like to make a function that will create a timestamp whenever a particular keyword is mentioned within a variable I created. The variable is meant to get the last row and column within a sheet. Then I would like to place the timestamp value into a particular cell in a specified sheet. How would I successfully complete this function? A portion of my code is below for reference:

```
//Section J: Create Timestamp for last entry Item
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
const sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Dewar ID');
var last_entry = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(),52,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

if (last_entry != "Item 9")
var item1 = sheet4.getRange(3,4).setValues(new Date ());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk(keyword,osh,ocell) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  if(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValue().toString().includes(keyword)) {
    osh.getRange(ocell).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

Comment: Are osh and ocell meant to be variables , also is the keyword meant to be in quotation marks in the IF statement. When I try an d run the code I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')`

Comment: You  may just wish to define them in the function it's up to you.  osh is the output sheet and ocell in the range of the output cell.

Comment: Got it, it is running successfully. Thanks